# When i do a debug, the pictures went out of place, anyone know why?

Tags: wpf

I'm using WPF xaml. When i do a debug, the pictures ran out of place from what the design is shown. Any one know why? Beside codes what do i have to add in? Sry first time posting in here. What else must i add on? Btw i'm using VS2010.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="C:TV\TV_Page_02.jpg" UseLayoutRounding="True"></Image>
    <Image Source="C:TV\2.jpg" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="19,74,115,72"></Image>
    <Image Source="C:TV\1.jpg" UseLayoutRounding="True" Margin="123,53,47,72"></Image>
</Grid>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright, here's the issue:

"Layout rounding should be used in UI scenarios where the exact location of objects can be sacrificed for overall appearance of the application. Since rounding of layout parameters occurs when using this feature, precise element placement is lost. A few of the effects layout rounding can have on exact layout are…

·width and or height of elements may grow or shrink by at most1 pixel

· placement of an object can move by at most 1 pixel

· centered elements can be vertically or horizontally off center by at most1 pixel

If your app has an unexpectedly blurry image or icon, fuzzy lines or borders that should be crisp, or grid banding try using layout rounding." - Quoted from "WPF Text Blog".

Here's the link to read more about this property:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx

Now I guess we now what is the problem (UseLayoutRounding=true). Just remove this property